# Add html 'data-' element to selectlistitem from code when creating a selectlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, listbox, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm building a selectlist which will have different groupings based on the value in the 'data-' element. For example: the group headers would be something like "Yellow Fruit", "Red Fruit", "Purple Fruit"...and the selectitems would be grouped under the specific group header based on the value in the selectitem's data-.  The selectitem's text is the name of the fruit and its value is the fruit's product code.
Note:
The group headers need to be clickable.  If the user were to click the group header then everything within that group would be removed and placed into another listbox and vice versa.  I'm not able to accomplish this with `optGroup` within the `SelectListItem`.

Comment: Not using the `DropDownListFor()` method

Comment: You could manually generate the `<select>` element using a loop to generate the options but that would result in loss of 2-way model binding, validation etc. Why do you need a `data-` attribute?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I'm trying to stay away from manually creating for those very reasons lol. I'm trying to create groupings based off the values in the data- element.

Comment: You should explain in the question what your trying do do and why (there will no doubt be a better option than using a `data-` attribute, but not clear what you mean by _create groupings_)

Comment: I've updated the question to better explain what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: You have tagged this MVC-5 so you can create options groups using the `Group` property of `SelectListItem`.

Comment: Researching this now. I'm relatively new to mvc. Thank you so very much for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128833/discussion-between-michael-harvey-and-stephen-muecke).